# c++ program using pointers to pass/return a 2d array prints nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm still trying to get the hang of passing/returning arrays to and from a function using pointers, or was it also called dynamic array?

It's still not clear to me how to pass arrays/return arrays this way ( Please explain )

And I really can't find the solution online. I tried basing my code with materials available online but nothing seems to work.

In my code below, the program should call the `makeMS` function to create a n x n magic square (ms) the n size is given by the user, which should then be returned.

After that, the ms array would be passed to the `printTable` function to print the array elements.

And the `isMagicSquare` would take the array and checks if all the rows, columns and, diagonals would have the same sum (magic constant).

**Please, any help would be amazing**

also here is a screenshot of the output
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int i, j, n, num;

using namespace std;

//Function to check if array is a magic square or not
bool isMagicSquare (int **magicSquare, int n) {
    
    //get the sums of the 2 diagonals if the sum is the same
    
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum1 += magicSquare[i][i];  
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum2 += magicSquare[i][n-1-i];
    }
    
    if(sum1 != sum2) 
        return false;
    
        
    //Now for the sums of rows
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        int rowSum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            rowSum += magicSquare[i][j];
        }
        
        if (rowSum != sum1) 
            return false;
        
    }
    
    //sum of the columns
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        int colSum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            colSum += magicSquare[j][i];
        }
        
        if ( sum1 != colSum )
        return false;
        
    
}

return true;

}

// Print magic square 
void printTable (int **magicSquare, int n) {
    
       
    
    cout << "The Magic Square for n=" << n << ":\nSum of "
   
    "each row or column " << n * (n*n+1) / 2 << ":\n\n";  
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
    {  
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)  
            cout << setw(5) << magicSquare[i][j] << " ";  
        cout << endl; 
    }  
    
}

//Function that constructs the magic square
int **makeMS (int n) {
    
    int **tableArr = new int*[n];
    
    //makes all slots 0
    memset(tableArr, 0, sizeof(tableArr));
    
    
    //Position of 1st number
    i = 0;
    j = n/2;
    
    //Step to magic square construction
    for (num = 1; num <= n*n;) {
        
        //if the position of k + 1 is tableArr[-1][n], 3rd condition
        if ( i == -1 && j == n) {
            
            j -= 1;
            i += 2;
        }
        
        else {
            
    
            if (j == n) {
                j = 0;
            }
            
            if(i < 0) {
                i = n - 1; 
            }
            
        }
        
        //3rd condition (occupied slot)
        if (tableArr[i][j]) {
            i+= 2;
            j -= 1;
            continue;
        }
        
        else {
            tableArr[i][j] = num++; //set number  
  
        j++; i--; //1st step
        
        }   
    }

    return tableArr;
    
 
}

int main () {
    
    int sum;
    int **magicSquare;

        cout << "Please enter size of array [n] \n";
        cin >> n; 
        
        if(n%2) {
            magicSquare = makeMS(n);
        }
        else
            cout << "Please enter an odd no for the array size";
    
    printTable(magicSquare, n);

    
    if (isMagicSquare(magicSquare, n)) {
        cout << "\n \nThe Matrix/Array is a Magic Square \n\n" ;
            
    }
    
    else {
        cout << "\n The Matrix/Array is NOT a Magic Square";
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn about multidimensional arrays in C++ or do you not care about the implementation details and just want a matrix datastructure for whatever problem you're actually solving? If the latter, just use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and be happy.

Comment: `tableArr` is filled with null pointers, you need to allocate them. Do you really need to use raw arrays? `std::vector` would be simpler and safer

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your 2-d array allocation and initialization in makeMS method as shown below-

```
int** tableArr = new int* [n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   tableArr[i] = new int[n] {0};
}
```

memset method call is not required due to above initialization in for loop.

Comment: The memset is wrong in more then one way. You are however right that your code zeroes out the elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here being: **using c-style data structures** like arrays[], [][], **, etc.

Unfortunately c++ does not come with a built in matrix data structure (there are many libs providing matrix implementations like [eigen](/questions/tagged/eigen)). I highly recommend using a proper matrix library. It is also possible to make a sparse matrix easily with (tracking max dimensions yourself if that is needed), example:

```
std::map< std::tuple<size_t, size_t>, int> sparse_matrix;
```